# embedded poky dist. do not return any thing when execute python or gcc from bash (Yocto Project)

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am working on Yocto Project and  Raspberry Pi

Everything was working fine until I did some modifications in my own layer, when i copied image to sd Card and run rpi
It works well but does not respond when I execute some packages such python and gcc

For example, when I run Python

```
rootraspberrypi:~# python 
rootraspberrypi:~#
```

bash do not return any thing !

but when execute busybox it works fine and return all function exist in image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem

Error was in SD memory formating, I did not format the memory properly and caused the problem in the rootfs

I used this script [mk2parts.sh](https://github.com/jumpnow/meta-rpi/blob/jethro/scripts/mk2parts.sh) from [meta-rpi](https://github.com/jumpnow/meta-rpi/)  and everything became works fine

Answer (score 0):

Does `python --version` work?  After running python, what does `echo $?` produce?

Comment: python --version 
No response
echo $? print 0  on screen

Comment: Another thing I noticed In the past when everything works just fine, it did not appear caret _ Now appear in console –